# Android: onCreateOptionsMenu() item action

Tags: android, menu, options-menu

I have a menu created through:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add("Email");

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  }
```

But I can't remember how to set a onclicklistener so when its selected I can run my email function.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Override `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`. So it would be like

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0:
            // do whatever
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Since this has gotten so many points, I should note that it *is* very good to add ID's to the menu options.  A good way to ensure they are always unique is to define them in an `ids.xml` resource that is put in the `res/values` folder.

ids.xml

```
<resources>
    <item name="menu_action1" type="id"/>
    <item name="menu_action2" type="id"/>
    <item name="menu_action3" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Then when you override the `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method,  you can use the IDs like so:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

  menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.menu_action1, Menu.NONE, R.string.menu_action1);
  menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.menu_action2, Menu.NONE, R.string.menu_action1);

  return true;
}
```

Override `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_action1:
            // do whatever
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_action2:
            // do whatever
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The reason you do this is the `Activity` would override this with menu options, but `Fragments` can also add their own menu items.  Using the `ids.xml` ensures the IDs are unique no matter which order they are placed.

Comment: As a good programming practice, I'd use ids rather than hardcoding the numbers in the case.

Answer (score 18):

That won't work. You should define IDs for your menu items:

```
public static final int MENU_ADD = Menu.FIRST;
public static final int MENU_DELETE = Menu.FIRST + 1;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_ADD, Menu.NONE, "Add");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_DELETE, Menu.NONE, "Delete");
    return true;
}

   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case MENU_ADD:

            return true;
        case MENU_DELETE:

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

From [Android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle item selection
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case R.id.new_game:
    newGame();
    return true;
case R.id.help:
    showHelp();
    return true;
default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.itemid:
            //do cool stuff
            break;
          }
     }
```